# WSL Linux /proc/task/children doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, forking

I'm running WSL Ubuntu on Windows 10. I have a task to:

- create an app that builds a small process tree in C++ (done)
- watch tree through pstree (done, all processes are running, stopped by `getchar()`
- And watch what does `task//children` folder contains in `/proc`.

The problem is there's nothing like `children` directory present here. I `cd` to directory by PID and open task directory. There I see another directory with same PID and nothing else.  When I open this directory I see no `children` file either.

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit/update*: I found that this is configured by `CONFIG_PROC_CHILDREN` which seems to be disabled by default. How can I enable this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using WSL1.  But first ...

> when I open this directory I see no "children" dir either

On my system, `children` is a file, not a directory.  Just to make sure you are looking for the right type of item, but I'm guessing you would have spotted it even if it was a file instead of a directory :-).

```
$ cat /proc/1/task/1/children
9 10
```

But as I said, I'm guessing this based on your WSL version.  Confirm the WSL version (1 or 2) by (from PowerShell or CMD):

```
wsl -l -v
```

If, as I suspect, it's WSL1, then it won't have support for `CONFIG_PROC_CHILDREN`.  WSL1 does not use a real Linux kernel, but is instead a "translation" layer which converts Linux kernel syscalls to those of the Windows kernel.  Either there's not a direct equivalent to map in Windows, or the WSL team chose not to implement that nuance.

WSL2, on the other hand, does use a real Linux kernel ([Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel)).  I'm guessing that you are on WSL1 since pretty much all versions of the WSL2 kernel have had `CONFIG_PROC_CHILDREN=y` in their `.config`.  Here's a link to the [oldest WSL2 kernel config settings](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/blob/linux-msft-wsl-4.19.y/Microsoft/config-wsl) where you can confirm.

To really do the type of kernel/process inspection you are trying, you'll want to be on WSL2.  WSL1 is great for a lot of tasks, but the addition of the "real" kernel in WSL2 is going to smooth out a lot of inconsistencies you might find in the WSL1 "translation" mechanism.

If you have WSL2 installed and configured, you can convert your instance with (again, from PowerShell or CMD):

```
wsl --export <distroname> backup.tar
wsl --set-version <distroname> 2
```

Comment: Man you made my day. I indeed had a WSL1 version, and after converting to second, I got the task to its end. Children is a file indeed, that's a tilted typo, sorry :S